# 13.04 Installs the wrong ISO

Tags: cpu

When I download the 64 bit 13.04, no other options are given and the download just begins. I am using a MAC and this default is the wrong processor.

Comment: I'm not a MAC user and has never been. Are you saying you want to run Ubuntu on top of MAC OS using Virtualbox or something similar? If that is the case, try downloading the 32-bit(x86) version as older hardware does not support 64-bit(x64)

Comment: What is being downloaded and why do you think it is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the 32-bit ISO from the ubuntu.com website here:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop